# Bottle server route to multiple html pages

Tags: python, html, server, bottle

I have set up a bottle server and I want to launch both index.html and second.html pages which are located in my main website folder. The code I've previously used to display index.html is:

```
@route('/')
def server_static(filename="index.html"):
    return static_file(filename, root='./index.html')
```

At the moment, it won't work and it will throw a server error saying that the file does not exist. How can I launch **not only** my index, but my other pages as well?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: @LoganBertram I basically have my folder and inside I literarily have index.html, secondpage.html, thirdpage.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root` needs to be the path to the folder containing your files, not the file itself:

```
@route('/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/path/to/files')
```

So requesting `example.com/index.html` will serve the file at `/path/to/files/index.html`.

Comment: But what about the other pages? Not just my index.

Comment: Edited.  Your example made it look like you only wanted to serve index.html using this route and would create other routes for serving other files.  This will serve any file in your root folder which is provided matching the route pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I realised and edited my question. Thanks for your answer. Does that mean that I have to put literally @route('/<filename>')? And then just indicate my folder's path in the return statement? - I am completely new to this, so I am trying to understand. :)

Comment: @user3755632 It's no problem. Yes, you put that literally and set the absolute path to your files as `root`.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you! I added the folder path just now which is root=‘A:\files\new\webapp’  and it won’t work :/. It will say file not found etc.

Comment: @user3755632 I'm sorry you're still having trouble.  [Here's](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#routing-static-files) the Bottle documentation on the issue. You should examine logs for errors. Go back to relative path with `root = './'` and check file permissions.